# Rendering content / partials as it becomes available using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

I have a website that has a ton of different sports data on it. Some of the data is not cached and not ready to render as fast as other portions of the website. It is built on top of Ruby on Rails 4 + jquery and I plan on introducing EmberJS. This is more of a generic type question in that I'm looking for a solution for how to partially load content as it becomes available on the site without blocking the initial page load. Facebook once had a great post on this on their engineering blog, and I can't seem to find it for the life of me.

With frameworks such as jQuery and EmberJS out there, is there a technique/name for the practice used to tie into a backend like Ruby on Rails to partially load sections of the site as it becomes available, asynchronously not blocking the rest of the page from loading? Can Ruby on Rails partials come into play here?

Comment: Using Ajax you can query your backend and let it return partials to update parts of your site, maybe by timer intervals. jQyery is great for this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Rails partials are always pre-rendered, and served up on page load, so I don't think that will be the best solution for you. You can have your Rails application serve up a front-end application that makes AJAX calls back to Rails to fetch all of your data, so everything will be handled asynchronously. You would use a client-side template to create the page that you're looking for.

I haven't done any work with Ember, but this would be pretty simple to do in Backbone or Angular. Here's two quick videos to explain Backbone views (watch both of them). Additionally, this should give you an idea of how it works in other JS frameworks as well.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnZ-X_dlO9k

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idb4H29EpdI

Backbone views are comparable to Rails controllers, and Backbone templates are comparable to Rails views. This is missing the AJAX part, but it's not a very big jump from this to adding some AJAX logic.